# How to kill activity on back button press

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a small issue in my android app. I want to kill the current activity when the back button is pressed. I have included this in my code:

```
   public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        this.Finish();
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
```

But the activity doesn't finish when I go back to the previous page. I have an external callback method in this activity that is called even when I'm not on this activity. The method get's called as many times as I open the activity so I figured the activity is not getting closed properly. For example the method (SignalR callback) doesn't get called when I don't open the activity but as I open and close it, the method keeps getting called the number of times I opened and closed the activity when ever there a function callback. 
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Tigger no, you are not supposed to call lifecycle methods, the system is.

Comment: @Ahmed why don't you just unregister your callback when the Activity stops (e.g. in `onStop()`)?

Comment: @Karakuri Ohh yeah I can do that

Comment: @Karakuri I suppose your answer is the correct one since I'm supposed to be unsubscribing the callback in onStop()

Comment: In that case i will post it as an answer

Comment: cool. I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unsubscribe your callback in `onStop()`